# Android Custom Project Template not showing in "Create New Project" dialog

Tags: android, android-studio

I create my own project template and put it on the below path in Mac OS.

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/templates/activities
```

now when I restart the studio try to create a new project with my own template then I am not showing that template in the "Create New Project" dialog.

[image: Here is dialog for project templates]

Your help will be appreciate

Thank you in Advance.